# iOS App fetching data via ASP .NET WebAPI

Tags: ios, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, azure-sql-database

I have a web app built with ASP.NET Web API and I'm about to begin developing an iOS app for the first time.

I'm wondering - since I have API endpoints configured already for my web app, can I reuse these for my iOS app?

I'm not sure how data fetching works with iOS and want to make sure I'm not making a mistake by assuming I can just reuse my WebAPI endpoints to fetch JSON payloads.

Comment: Not sure I understood your question. Are you asking if it is possible to communicate via HTTP from an iOS app to an ASP.NET Web API application? Or are you looking for a method to automatically create objects and mappings to Web API endpoints (similar to WCF proxies)?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma just wondering if fetching/saving data via REST API calls is the norm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RESTful services address many issues we had with the old Web Services (SOAP-based) when implementing them as an abstraction layer between a thin client and a data-driven back-end (cumbersome middlewares, complex protocols, difficult re-usability, etc.).

I believe that RESTful services excels in mobile environments and are also the de facto standard when in need of a service layer that is interoperable, lightweight and reusable.

Seems to me that your use case is very common, and a Web API back-end is the best choice when you have heterogeneous clients accessing to your API, so if you already have this kind of application do not hesitate to use it for fetching/manipulating data.

Comment: You rock.  Thanks Federico.